# 500 error: uploading files (duplicate primary key)

Tags: assets, upload, files

Afternoon all - odd issue where created some new asset folders and adding new files is timing out. If I view the folder in question (on the server) I can see the file has been successfully uploaded but this isn’t reflected in the back-end. Craft 2.4. Console Log is returning a POST `/admin/actions/assets/uploadFile 500 (Internal Server Error)` response.

Checking the craft logs it is throwing a `Duplicate entry '3996' for key 'PRIMARY'` error in the `craft_assetfiles` table. It looks like somewhere between builds/deployments the `craft_assetfiles` table has got out of sync. I've tried updating the Asset and Search indexes but with no success.

Any thoughts on debugging or resolving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay - have managed to resolve this. Needed to reset the auto increment value in the `craft_elements` to greater than the max(id) for the `craft_assetfiles` - not sure how those got out of synch but that seems to have resolved it. Hallelujah!